# Pyspark - How to set the schema when reading parquet file from another DF?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I have DF1 with schema:

```
df1 = spark.read.parquet(load_path1)
df1.printSchema()

root
 |-- PRODUCT_OFFERING_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATED_BY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATION_DATE: string (nullable = true)
```

and DF2:

```
df2 = spark.read.parquet(load_path2)
df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- PRODUCT_OFFERING_ID: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATED_BY: decimal(38,10) (nullable = true)
 |-- CREATION_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Now I want to Union these 2 dataframes..
Sometime it gives errors when I try to UNION these 2 DFs because of different schemas..

How to set for DF2 to have exact same schema (during the load time) as DF1?

I tried with:

```
df2 = spark.read.parquet(load_path2).schema(df1.schema)
```

Getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'StructType' object is not callable
```

Or should I CAST it instead (once DF2 is read)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move **`.schema()`** before **`.parquet()`** then spark will read the parquet file with the specified schema

```
df2 = spark.read.schema(df1.schema).parquet(load_path2)
```