# When I read in .parquet files using PySpark and print the schema, I lose the column headers I had set in the first row

Tags: database, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

Example of how I am reading in the files:

```
parquet_file = spark.read.format("parquet") \
               .option("header","true") \
               .option("inferSchema","true") \
               .load(directory_path)
```

When I run this...

```
parquet_file.printSchema()
```

It returns...

```
root 
|-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c2: string (nullable = true)
|-- _c3: string (nullable = true)
```

I thought the `.option("header","true")` would tell Spark to use the first row as column headers but I guess not. I have also written the schema out and tried to add `.schema(customSchema)` before the `.load(directory_path)` but when apply the schema, all of the rows show null values.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this issue?

Let me know if I can supply more info to help you help me

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The options you have above are typical for reading in a CSV.  Try just reading in the parquet without omitting the first line (etc)

```
parquet_DF = spark.read.parquet(directory_path)
parquet_DF.printSchema()
```

Comment: I tried this. It returned the same schema with c0,c1,c2...

Comment: Can you share the parquet you're reading?  I'm reading CSV, saving parquet, and then reading the parquet in the google collab here (see the cells at the bottom): https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18Bj3AxBGcGQ3wWpvreP84vzF94HJt1Lb?usp=sharing

Comment: Something I didn't think of before, you may want to also look at the schema before writing your parquet `df.printSchema()` to also check that it's defined before you save the parquet.

Comment: So unfortunately I can't share the file. I am not able to assign the schema to the files while they are in .csv format because the schema is nested (not flat). The problem right now is that when I apply my nested schema to the parquet files, upon reading them in, the values go null. When I do a print schema... it shows that the correct schema is applied

Comment: It's good the schema is being set, but clearly bad that it's null. Can you share the code for the schema assignment?  I know you talk about it in your original question, but it's imporant to see what you're working with.  It might be you're not setting the schema before loading the parquet, that has already been answered on stack overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60399235/pyspark-how-to-set-the-schema-when-reading-parquet-file-from-another-df